# Can we please remove [imageio] as a synonym of [javax.imageio]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process, tag-disambiguation

I was trying to tag a question ([Getting Memory Leakage - NSData conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37936060/getting-memory-leakage-nsdata-conversion)) for the [Image I/O framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_basics/ikpg_basics.html) used in Cocoa and Cocoa Touch. That is the framework employed by the code in that question. When I tried tagging the question as [imageio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imageio), the system replaced it with [javax.imageio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javax.imageio) (for which [imageio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imageio) is a synonym) and used that tag, even though that's not appropriate.

Can we please remove the [imageio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imageio) synonym for [javax.imageio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javax.imageio)?

And can we then create an [imageio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imageio) tag (or a [imageio-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imageio-framework) or whatever) for the Cocoa and Cocoa Touch Image I/O framework?

Comment: I'd prefer "imageio-framework". If we just call it "imageio", it will still be added to questions about javax.imageIO .

Comment: I'm sympathetic to that position. My only observation is that this isn't consistent with many other Cocoa framework tags that don't bear the `-framework` suffix. But if we need that to disambiguate from the `javax` rendition, I'm OK w that.

Comment: BTW, when we fix this tag, I'm willing to go and retag the dozen or so old iOS/MacOS questions which intended to specify the Cocoa framework, but are incorrectly tagged with `javax.imageio`. (These are found by searching for "[javax.imageio] [objective-c]".)

Answer (score 5):

It might be a good idea to have a tag for apple-imageio (or is that cocoa-imageio?).

You might have an acceptable case for removing [imageio] completely and only using [javax.imageio] and [apple-imageio], but there's no reason for that apple/cocoa framework to take over the existing imageio tag.

Answer (score -1):

The true question here are:

- Is the Apple API `apple.imageio`/`objective-c.imageio` worth a tag? The API doesn't seem to be something wide IMO. If you use that tag but forget to use another wider relevant tag, you might not get answers because people will follow the main tag and not all the little ones. So I think it would be more wise to have the user use a more generic, and followed tag than the opposite.
- Does an `imageio` tag have any real value without being link to any framework/implementation? Considering we're on Stack Overflow where we talk about code mainly I guess not.

A thing that I don't know about Stack Overflow: Does something exist like having a hierarchy of tags, so if something is tagged `toto.titi` everyone following `toto` will see it? I guess not, because the implementation/organisation of this wouldn't be easy, but I prefer to ask just in case.

Comment: In terms of whether the Cocoa Image I/O warrants a tag, while it isn't the most widely used framework, it's also not entirely arcane. For example, I searched for a single common Image I/O function (`CGImageSourceCreateWithData`), and there were 208 questions using that one function. Does that suggest that Cocoa's Image I/O framework warrants a tag? I would have thought so. Regardless, it's certainly the case that this synonym should be removed, IMHO.

Comment: Regarding your taxonomic/hierarchical tag naming convention, that seems like a completely different topic.

Comment: @Rob that was just something that i wondered on the way. About if it warrant a tag, how many people will follow a tag which have only 208 questions ? And would ave those208 question proplery tagged ? If no one follow the tag, you have way less chance to have answers. And of course since you have a specific tag, you may forget to put a more general and followed tag. I just wanted to point out the relevant questions here and i gave my opinion about it.

Comment: The idea of hierarchical tags has been asked and rejected many, many times, mostly due to no one wanting to maintain the hierarchy.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan as i thought, i just wondered if it was existing but i didin't know it, of course if not it would has been suggested and rejected already. Thanks for the answer